# If I create a succesful dot com company utilizing google app engine/datastore will google own it?

Tags: google-app-engine

Or is it easier to host my own website and database.

The main reason I would use [google app engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html) is the "free" hosting and scalability;

Has anyone got experience using app engine, was it a good experience ?

Comment: Will google own it if you create an unsuccessful dot company?

Comment: I've used App Engine for a lot of things, and I'd say I've had a good experience so far. A few minor hiccups, but many fewer than if I'd had to host it myself, and free as well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about startups

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no, Google does not own either your code or your data. Both of them are completely yours. Google only provides hosting for it - they have no more claim on your data and IP than Amazon does if you go with EC2. Take a look at section 6.3 of the [terms](http://code.google.com/appengine/terms.html).

I'm running [mapfaire.com](http://www.mapfaire.com) on the App Engine and I'm having a very good experience. I intend to continue using it for all my applications.

Comment: thanks, I just thought it seemed a little to good to be true, a free quota of 5million hits a month ... ?

Comment: I think someone did an analysis on that... If you do actually get that many hits, and you have adsense on your site, then Google makes far more money than they lose on hosting costs :D

Comment: And you feel this answers your question, then you might want to mark it correct rather than upvote it...